# For loop Looping

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

My problem is I created 8 viewpager in tab layout. Suppose I want 3 view pages, which I need but I want to delete the rest.

This is my code to add tab and I use for loop to delete the remaining tabs but there is the error **"Invalid index 6, size is 6"** and as a result, it doesn't fulfill my requirement. How do I adjust my for looping function.

```
 BasePagerAdapter adapter = new BasePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
    Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
    Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
    Tab4 tab4 = new Tab4();
    Tab5 tab5 = new Tab5();
    Tab6 tab6 = new Tab6();
    Tab7 tab7 = new Tab7();
    Tab8 tab8 = new Tab8();
    Tab9 tab9 = new Tab9();

    adapter.addFragment(tab1, "All");
    adapter.addFragment(tab2, "1");
    adapter.addFragment(tab3, "2");
    adapter.addFragment(tab4, "3");
    adapter.addFragment(tab5, "4");
    adapter.addFragment(tab6, "5");
    adapter.addFragment(tab7, "6");
    adapter.addFragment(tab8, "7");
    adapter.addFragment(tab9, "8");

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Creating our pager adapter


    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    int ans =3;
    for(int i =8 ; ans<=i ; ans++) {

        adapter.removeFragment(ans);
    }
```

Comment: where is ``ans``?

Comment: What is the point of `i`? `for(int i =8 ; ans<=i ; ans++)` is same as `for (; ans <= 8; ans++)`, since you never change `i`. Instead, try `for (int i = 8; i >= ans; i--) { adapter.removeFragment(i); }` to remove them from the end, so index values stay intact during removal.

Comment: sry, question edited

Comment: then ans++; before the loop to be 4 that will leafe for you 3 tabs you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int ans=3;         //you need only 3

for(int i =8 ; i>ans ; i--)   //i for total count. make sure that size
{

    adapter.removeFragment(i);//it remove the pager 8,7,6,5,4
}
```

Comment: i >= ans ..if you want remove 3 means use = or just > is enough

Comment: @Andreas  said that in a comment before

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mush have used `List`.

When remove element at index `i` from `List`, elements which have index bigger than `i` are shifted.

In your case, when `ans` become `6`, `List` has six element and its index can be `0 to 5`.